# Server side analytics of outbound links

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

The problem: We count clicks on external links with Google Analytics (GA). But because external links are opened in a new tab, we are not 100% sure that browser's tab was really opened and that a third-party site was really loaded even in opened tab.

The solution: Do not open direct links to 3-d party web-sites directly in the new tab, but only through some interceptor that will collect statistic on a server side before  redirection to the target url. Thus, we will be able to to catch the moment of loading a third page in a new browser window.

Therefore, we need a service that will take full URL as a parameter, collect statistics, and then redirects to the passed URL, like this:
https://magicclickcounter.com/abc?url_to_redirect=http://urltoexternal.link/123  which will collect statistics and redirects to http://urltoexternal.link/123

Any ideas how to achieve this with GoogleAnalytics?

UPD: Firebase DynamicLinks is not appropriate for us because we have to use shortened urls(deep API integration) or there will be no statistic for full urls created manually or via SDK-builder.

UPD: The main problem in our case is that we use a HTML canvas in our page and "clicking area" is inside canvas. Therefore we use next code to open a new window:

```
this.pixiLayout.App.renderer.view.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (this.pixiLayout.externalUrl) {
        window.open(this.pixiLayout.externalUrl, '_blank');
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't see how this approach will help you detect the load of 3rd party page. This will only catch the fact of 'redirect' that is exactly the same as redirect following the link click.

Comment: @ДмитроБулах, not really. From redirect to actual page load there is almost no obstacles. But when you click a link and open it for a load in a new tab, there could be at least: browser policy, plugins that block external windows, lazy tabs.

Comment: yes but as far as there's plain `<a href="http://urltoexternal.link/123 ">` in your original solution you'll end up eventually dealing with the same links to  https://magicclickcounter.com/abc?url_to_redirect=http://urltoexternal.link/123 and the same obstacles remain. the only difference would be that way to `urltoexternal.link` get's longer and slower because of redirect

Comment: @ДмитроБулах Actually we could not use simple <a href=""> tag in our web-page because "clicking area" is inside canvas. To open clicked link we use 
`window.open(this.externalUrl, '_blank');` in "onClick()" handler. Therefore there are lot of chases for false positive triggers in pure JS solution like Google Analytics.